# Find sub-sets of vanishing additions or subtractions from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Let's say I have a list `L` containing `n` numerical numbers. Now I want to find all sub-sets of `m < n` different elements out of `L` such that at least one combination of summing or subtracting those `m` elements with each other gives zero to numerical precision. Is it possible to do that in Mathematica in a convenient way? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: With a looping construct, the subtraction portion is could be implemented using `Differences`. As the documentation for it notes, `Differences` can be equivalently implemented using `ListConvolve` so you may be able to use that to implement the summing portion.

Comment: What do you mean by "summing or subtracting those `m` elements"? If it's the whole list, I'm not sure what you mean by "subtract". Summing makes sense, though.

Comment: I mean taking the `m` numbers, attaching all possible phase combinations of plus or minus to each one and then summing them (which yields a single scalar in each case) to see if any one of these summations gives zero.

Comment: Could set it up as an integer linear programming problem. Coefficients must all be in the set `{-1,0,1}`. If you insist that `m` be nonzero then the sum of absolute values of the coeffs must be `m`. A slightly complicated setup but not unreasonably difficult to code.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. I would be interested in seeing that solution, if you've got the time, since I imagine it will be much faster than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution

Suppose the list is

```
list = Range[-3, 3]
(* {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, -3} *)
```

Then, the set of all subsets of, say, size 3 is

```
sets = Subsets[list, {3}];
```

We define a list of `signs` that give all possible combinations of plusses and minuses to attach to each subset:

```
signs = Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]
(* {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}
    , {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Then, we want to select from the list `sets` the subsets that will be zero when dotted with at least one of the elements of `signs`.  To make this happen, we will use `Select`, which takes as a second argument an expression that will accept an element `a` of `sets` as an input and output `True` if `a` `Dot`ted with one of the elements of `sign` is zero and `False` otherwise. `Select` then keeps the ones that evaluate to `True`. The expression

```
Select[sets, (Or @@ Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[#, x]] /@ signs) &]
```

results in

```
(* {{-3, -2, -1}, {-3, -2, 1}, {-3, -1, 2}, {-3, 0, 3}
    , {-3, 1, 2}, {-2, -1, 1}, {-2, -1, 3}, {-2, 0, 2}
    , {-2, 1, 3}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 2}, {-1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}  *)
```

#### Explanation

Let's pick the condition function apart. First,

```
Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[a, x]]
```

is a function that accepts an input `x` (which will be from `signs`), `Dot`s it with `a` (which will be an element of `sets`) and compares it to `0`, yielding `True` if it is equal to 0. For instance,

```
Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[{-1, 0, 1}, x]][{1, -1, 1}]
```

will yield `True` while

```
Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[{-1, 0, 1}, x]][{-1, -1, 1}]
```

will yield `False`. Then, for a particular `a` from `sets`, we `Map` this function over `signs` to yield all the possible comparisons:

```
Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[{-1, 0, 1}, x]] /@ signs
(* {True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True} *)
```

Finally, we `Apply` `Or` to this list to see if it at least one of the elements is `True`:

```
Or @@ Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[{-1, 0, 1}, x]] /@ signs
(* True *)
```

Finally, in order to make this work as the second argument of `Select`, we have to turn it into a function that will accept an element of `sets` as an input. Thus:

```
(Or @@ Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[#, x]] /@ signs) &
```

This turns the expression into a pure function whose input goes where the `#` is. For instance, we can see that

```
(Or @@ Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[#, x]] /@ signs) & [{-1, 0, 1}]
```

is the same as what we just did in parts above. Since `Select` will go one-by-one through the list `sets`, we get to just call

```
Select[sets, (Or @@ Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[#, x]] /@ signs) &]
```

#### Automate over all subset lengths

Finally, we can do this for every subset length (although, of course, this problem grows *really* fast, so user beware) as follows. We will do, as an example,

```
list = Range[-2, 2]
(* {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2} *)
```

Then,

```
Table[
 Select[
  Subsets[list, {m}]
  , (Or @@ Function[{x}, 0 == Dot[#, x]] /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, {m}]) &
 ]
, {m, 1, Length@list}]
```

yielding

```
{
 {{0}}
 , {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}
 , {{-2, -1, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 2}}
 , {{-2, -1, 0, 1}, {-2, -1, 1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1, 2}}
 , {{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}}
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your last line of code, so I wrote my own: `result = {};
Do[If[! FreeQ[
    Table[signs[[i]].sets[[j]], {i, 1, Dimensions[signs][[1]]}] // 
     Chop, 0], result = Append[result, sets[[j]]];], {j, 1, 
  Dimensions[sets][[1]]}]`. However, my code seems to find way fewer results when the range gets bigger, and I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: @Kagaratsch. I have an updated (and significantly changed) version that seems to match yours. I haven't done any speed checking, so I don't  know which version is faster. I have included an explanation as to how it works. I have also generalized to get all the subsets of any length.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not thrilled with the question since it provided no example, but there was a serious response and also a request to see an ILP approach. Here is one such.

Start by creating an example.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
n = 10;
m = 4;
intset = RandomInteger[100, n]

(* Out[335]= {9, 78, 23, 59, 95, 51, 24, 29, 99, 68} *)
```

Now we set up the ILP. We have our `n` -1/0/1 variables as multipliers of the set elements, and variables denoting absolute values thereof (so must be greater-equal to the corresponding multipliers and their negatives). These absolute value variables must sum to `m`. To enforce that the absolute variables are never strictly larger than corresponding multipliers we use another pair of 0-1 variables, with sum not exceeding 1 for each pair. These get used in pairs of equations for each multiplier/absolute value pair. Details are left to the code below.

```
cvars = Array[c, n];
abscvars = Array[ac, n];
uvars = Array[u, n];
vvars = Array[v, n];
allvars = Join[cvars, abscvars, uvars, vvars];
c1 = Map[-1 <= # <= 1 &, cvars];
c2 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, abscvars];
c3 = MapThread[{#2 >= #1, #2 >= -#1} &, {cvars, abscvars}];
c4 = Total[abscvars] == m;
c5 = cvars.intset == 0;
c6 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, Join[uvars, vvars]];
c7 = MapThread[#1 + #2 <= 1 &, {uvars, vvars}];
c8 = MapThread[{#1 + #2 - 2*#3 == 0, #1 - #2 - 2*#4 == 
      0} &, {abscvars, cvars, uvars, vvars}];
constraints = 
  Flatten[{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, 
    Element[allvars, Integers]}];
```

Here we solve it and reform as subsets with negatives where indicated. I probably should have added some constraint to remove trivial duplicates (wherein one solution is the negative of another).

```
Map[intset*# &, (cvars /. Solve[constraints, allvars])] /. 
 0 :> Sequence[]

(* Out[350]= {{-78, 95, 51, -68}, {-95, 51, -24, 68}, {95, -51, 
  24, -68}, {78, -95, -51, 68}} *)
```

Here is a substantially larger example.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
n = 20;
m = 8;
intset = RandomInteger[1000, n]

(* Out[354]= {79, 679, 93, 887, 870, 398, 413, 796, 273, 288, 947, 708,
232, 488, 464, 760, 458, 482, 174, 502} *)

cvars = Array[c, n];
abscvars = Array[ac, n];
uvars = Array[u, n];
vvars = Array[v, n];
allvars = Join[cvars, abscvars, uvars, vvars];
c1 = Map[-1 <= # <= 1 &, cvars];
c2 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, abscvars];
c3 = MapThread[{#2 >= #1, #2 >= -#1} &, {cvars, abscvars}];
c4 = Total[abscvars] == m;
c5 = cvars.intset == 0;
c6 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, Join[uvars, vvars]];
c7 = MapThread[#1 + #2 <= 1 &, {uvars, vvars}];
c8 = MapThread[{#1 + #2 - 2*#3 == 0, #1 - #2 - 2*#4 == 
      0} &, {abscvars, cvars, uvars, vvars}];
constraints = 
  Flatten[{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, 
    Element[allvars, Integers]}];

Timing[subsets = 
   Map[intset*# &, (cvars /. Solve[constraints, allvars])] /. 
    0 :> Sequence[];]

Length[subsets]

(* Out[370]= {76.94338, Null}

Out[371]= 7952 *)
```

Here are the first few.

```
subsets[[1 ;; 5]]

(* {{-79, -679, -93, -887, 708, -232, 760, 
  502}, {-79, -679, -93, -887, 288, 232, 760, 
  458}, {-79, -679, -93, -887, 398, 708, 458, 
  174}, {-79, -679, -93, -870, -398, 947, 708, 
  464}, {-79, -679, -93, -870, 947, -488, 760, 502}} *)
```

At small risk for correctness this could be made faster by writing an explicit branch-and-prune loop, using approximate linear programming on the relaxed problems (built-in `Solve` code uses exact linear programming on those). Some idea of how such a loop might be done can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221333744_Making_Change_and_Finding_Repfigits_Balancing_a_Knapsack).

Comment: Thanks (belatedly) for the answer! I like to use answers here to learn both Mathematica-specific methods and general programming methods.